# Symfony 4 - How to Order BY but DISTINCT and a 2nd ORDER BY - Createquerybuilder?

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I am training on Symvony and CREATEQUERYBUILDER, I was ordering by a field to display data
I want to display data ORDERED BY Quantity left in stock but I want them also "grouped by" package ID.

I don't know how to group by but still display all the other products (like in my 2nd pic)
[image: With a GROUP BY]

If I don't GROUP BY, I get all the data but it doesn't respect "GROUP BY" package ID and product from package 1 and package 2 are entangled.
[image: Without a GROUP BY]

What I do is:

```
    public function findAllOrderByQuantity(): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('pack')
        ->orderBy( 'pack.quantity', 'ASC')
        ->groupBy('pack.packageId')
    ;
    

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->execute();
}
```

Could you please help me on that one? Thanks

Comment: Group by package id will group all rows for distinct package ids so in your can you will have 2 results like in first image, you question is a bit unclear please add some more detail how you would want the results to be shown

Comment: Do you mean `ORDER BY pack.packageId, pack.quantity` instead of `GROUP BY pack.packageId`?